# Google Maps show address on marker click

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, maps, reverse-geocoding

I have a map with multiple markers, defined by latitude and longitude.
I want to display the address of the marker when clicking the marker.
I thought this is a normal Google Maps feature, but when I click a marker nothing happens..

What do I have to do?

Comment: You probably should provide the platform and language you use first.. then we can help you. Also google map doesn't show the address of marker by defualt. you should use Reverse Geolocation to query a location for an address!

Comment: Oh sorry... it's simple HTML & javascript / jquery of course. Is there any other possible language to create a Google map?

Comment: Yes we have googlemaps on Android, IOS, Windows, Web and pretty much any platform available right now.
As I said there is no ready made way to do what you want, you should get Location of marker and using Reverse-Geolocation get the address of location.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 3):

Please provide ur API key to googleapi link, Map icon and co-ordinates also

```html
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key= provide your key here"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

 <script>
            

            var map, center = {lat: 10.382676, lng: 75.373828};
            if(window.innerWidth < 1200){
                center = {lat:10.382676, lng: 76.373828};
            }
 

            var hotels = [

                {
                    id: 1,
                    details: [
                        {title: "title name",
                            image: "image-url",
                            iconURL: "",
                            url: "page url"
                        }
                    ],
                    latLng: {lat: 9.978507, lng: 76.283289}
                },

                {
                    id: 6,
                    details: [
                        {
                            title: "title name",
                            image: "image-url",
                            iconURL: "",
                            url: "page url"
                        }],
                    latLng: {lat: 10.061291, lng: 77.063856}
                },




            ];




            function initMap() {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-container-1'), {
                    zoom: 8,
                    center: center
                });


            }

            var infoWindows = [];
            function loadHotelMarkerInfo(hotel){
                var info = $(document.createElement('div'));

                var infoWrapper = $(document.createElement('div'))
                        .attr('class', 'content-full')
                        .attr('id', hotel.id)
                        .appendTo(info);

                hotel.details.forEach(function(detail){
                    var titleWrapper = $(document.createElement('div'))
                            .attr('class', 'hotel-name')
                            .appendTo(infoWrapper);
                    var title = $(document.createElement('h1'))
                            .attr('class', 'titleClasses')
                            .html(detail.title)
                            .appendTo(titleWrapper);

                    var imgWrapper = $(document.createElement('div'))
                            .attr('class', 'hotel-image')
                            .appendTo(infoWrapper);
                    var img = $(document.createElement('img'))
                            .attr('class', 'img-responsive')
                            .attr('src', detail.image)
                            .appendTo(imgWrapper);

                    var txtWrapper = $(document.createElement('div'))
                            .attr('class', 'view-more')
                            .appendTo(infoWrapper);
                    var link = $(document.createElement('a'))
                            .attr('class', 'linkClasses')
                            .attr('href', detail.url)
                            .attr('target', "_blank")
                            .html("View more")
                            .appendTo(txtWrapper);
                });



                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: info.html(),
                    position: hotel.latLng,
                    maxWidth: 500
                });

                infoWindows.push(infoWindow);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: hotel.latLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: hotel.title,
                    icon: hotel.iconURL || "map-icon-image"
                });
                

                marker.addListener('click', function() {
                    infoWindows.forEach(function(infoWindow){
                        infoWindow.close();
                    });
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });

            }

            function loadHotels(){
                hotels.forEach(loadHotelMarkerInfo);
            }

            function greyoutWorld() {
                var world_geometry = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
                    query: {
                        select: 'geometry',
                        from: '1N2LBk4JHwWpOY4d9fobIn27lfnZ5MDy-NoqqRpk',
                        where: "ISO_2DIGIT IN ('IN')"
                    },
                    styles: [{
                        polygonOptions: {
                            fillColor: "GREEN",
                            strokeColor: "#ebebeb",
                            strokeWeight: "int"
                        },
                        polylineOptions: {
                            strokeColor: "#rrggbb",
                            strokeWeight: "int"
                        }
                    }],
                    map: map,
                    suppressInfoWindows: false
                });
            }

            initMap();
            loadHotels()

        </script>
```